# What the best way to debug gulp plugins during developing using webstorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to find the best way for debug gulp plugins during developing using webstorm. I have a project example and couple gulp plugins, and I want to trace and inspect the code in webstorm right after I run `gulp` command in terminal. Ideally I want to add `debugger` statement or breakpoint inside the webstorm to trace the code execution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this [guide](http://mrchief2000.wordpress.com/2014/06/13/running-gulp-tasks-with-jetbrains-webstorm/) (shameless self promotion) to setup your configurations. Then debug should just work as is.

Also, you won't need to run gulp from commandline separately, since webstorm will do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

this is an old question, and has an very good answer, 
here is another one with VS Code 
[debugging-gulp-in-VS-Code](https://hansrwindhoff.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/debugging-task-runner-tasks-like-gulp-with-visual-studio-code-editordebugger/)